# Double Hashing - remove and rehash function

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, double-hashing

I am working on a hashmap and having trouble with the remove function of a double hashing open address-style map. Lets say I insert on a table of size 10, and my 2 hash functions are as follows:

```
int hash( int key, std::size_t M ) { return key % M; }
int hash2( int key, std::size_t M ) { return key % (M-1) + 1; }
```

If I insert items with key 0, 10, and 20, the items will go to positions 0, 2, and 3.

```
<[ 0:A, - , 10:B, 20:C, - , - , - , - , - , - ]>
```

When removing an item, however, I want to remove the item AND rehash the following items in the same cluster. When I remove, say, item with key 0, it finds the item to remove no problem. But, it now needs to jump to index 2 - BUT IT CANT BECAUSE ITS USING THE KEY 0 AS ITS INCREMENT, so it jumps to index 1 instead. So, it will never find the subsequent items in the cluster. How do I do this???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you delete an item by placing a deleted marker in that position. For the purpose of searching, it is occupied, so items that collided and require probing to find are not orphaned. But when inserting, you can reuse that spot. If the number of deleted markers in your table becomes large, you can rehash the table to clean it up.

This lecture explains in more detail: [Open Addressing](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/open-addr.html)

Comment: Ok. But, lets say each time I delete something, I want to rehash everything in that cluster. How do I reach the next item without knowing its key?

Comment: I don't think you can. That's why you mark deletions, or rehash the whole table.

Comment: Ohhh man. Ok. What would be more efficient. To have a bool inside the node class called "deleted", or hold a vector of ints that hold the deleted indices?

Comment: What does your node class look like? If your table were holding object references, you can create a single "Deleted" object that is your marker. If your table holds something like ints, you can't do that because any marker value could be an actual value. You can have the deleted info in the node as you commented, or in a deleted table. I would go with in the node. If you have a deleted table, you would have to do a linear search of it. It's a time vs. space trade-off. But depending on what your node is now, it might take no extra space.

Comment: Instead of the mark_deleted idea, I think upon deletions I will just search the table and if the deleted node's hash1 function is the same as this one, I will reinsert.

Comment: @JohnCalderaio - What do you do when you insert, and both the first and the second hash function give you positions already occupied? How you deal with that could make your deletion plan not work.